# Laravel - array to string with 2 fields

Tags: php, laravel

```
$warehouses = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "warehouse 1",
    "pivot": {
        "product_id": "1",
        "warehouse_id": 1,
        "qty": 136.5
        }
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "warehouse 2",
    "pivot": {
        "product_id": "1",
        "warehouse_id": 2,
        "qty": 71.5
        }
    }
]
```

I need result like below.

```
$result = ["warehouse 1 - 136.5", "warehouse 2 -  71.5"];
```

plz help

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you show us what you have tried so far to get to that result?

Comment: Accepted answer from @mahradbt .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$result = [];
foreach($warehouses as $i){
  $result[] = $i['name'] . ' - ' . $i['pivot']['qty'];
}
```